# How should I avoid the "Alert" of unsaved changes when returning, if I have already saved the changes?

Tags: javascript, react-native, android-alertdialog, back

**How should I avoid the "Alert of unsaved changes" when returning** to the previous screen, if **I have already saved** the changes through a button created for that purpose?

I have created two pages to illustrate the problem I have: home page and a second page. Through the home page I can go to the second page, but if I save the data in this second page, the alert "Discard changes" appears anyway.

**HOME PAGE (homeTest)**

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Button } from 'react-native';

const homeTest = ({ navigation }) => {
    return (
        <View style={styles.containerStyle}>
            <Button styles={styles.button}
                title="GO TO SECOND PAGE"
                onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Second page')}
            />
        </View>
    )
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    containerStyle: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
    button: {
        fontSize: 24,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        color: "black",
        textAlign: 'center',
        marginBottom: 20,
        width: '100%',
        borderRadius:20,
    },
    txtInput: {
        textTransform: 'capitalize',
        top:3,
        paddingHorizontal: 20,
    }
});
  
export default homeTest;
```

**SECOND PAGE (secondPageTest)**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Button, Alert } from 'react-native';
import { TextInput, } from 'react-native-paper';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

const secondPageTest = ({ navigation }) => {
    
    const [name, setName] = useState('');
    const [age, setAge] = useState('');
    const [flagModify, setFlagModify] = useState(false);
    const hasUnsavedChanges = Boolean(flagModify);

    const checkAndSave = async (keyToSave, varName, varAge) => {
        if (varName == '' || varAge == '') {
            Alert.alert ("Attention", "You must complete the fields!");
            return;
        }

        let fields = {
            name: varName,
            age: varAge 
        };

        try {
            await AsyncStorage.setItem(keyToSave, JSON.stringify(fields));
        } catch(e) {
            console.warn("Error.");
            return;
        }
        console.warn("The data has been saved !. However the unsaved changes alert appear.");
        setFlagModify(false);
        navigation.navigate('Home page');
    };

    const updateField = (fieldValue, fieldName) => {
        setFlagModify(true);
        switch (fieldName) {
            case 'fName':
                return setName(fieldValue);
            case 'fAge':
                return setAge(fieldValue);
            default:
                return; 
        }
    };

    React.useEffect(() => {

        navigation.addListener('beforeRemove', (e) => {
            const action = e.data.action;
            if (!hasUnsavedChanges) {
              return;
            }
    
            e.preventDefault();
    
            Alert.alert(
              'Discard changes?',
              'You have unsaved changes. Are you sure to discard them and leave the screen?',
              [
                { text: "Don't leave", style: 'cancel', onPress: () => {} },
                {
                  text: 'Discard',
                  style: 'destructive',
                  onPress: () => navigation.dispatch(action),
                },
              ]
            );
        })
    }, [hasUnsavedChanges, navigation]);
    
    return (
        <>
            <View>
                <TextInput style={styles.txtInput}
                    label="name"
                    onChangeText={(value) => updateField(value, 'fName')}
                />
                <TextInput style={styles.txtInput}
                    label="age"
                    onChangeText={(value) => updateField(value, 'fAge')}
                />
                <Button styles={styles.button}
                    title="SAVE DATA"
                    onPress={() => checkAndSave('keySample', name, age)}
                />
                <Button styles={styles.button}
                    title="CANCEL"
                    onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home page')} 
                />
            </View>

        </>
    )
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    button: {
        fontSize: 24,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        color: "black",
        textAlign: 'center',
        marginBottom: 20,
        width: '100%',
        borderRadius:20,
    },
    txtInput: {
        textTransform: 'capitalize',
        top:3,
        paddingHorizontal: 20,
    }
});
  
export default secondPageTest;
```

Comment: Might need to be more specific with the test case and what you're trying to change if you say the code is working properly. Seems like updating the 'hasUnsavedChanges' const with a more robust conditional statement could give control over the alert.

Comment: Thanks @AndersElmgren I have added more code to explain myself

Answer (score 0):

You should change the hasUnsavedChanges to false when pressing the discard button.

```
const hasUnsavedChanges = useMemo(()=>{
 return Boolean(text)
},[text])

Alert.alert(
  'Discard changes?',
  'You have unsaved changes. Are you sure to discard them and leave the screen?',
  [
    { text: "Don't leave", style: 'cancel', onPress: () => {} },
    {
      text: 'Discard',
      style: 'destructive',
      onPress: () => {
        setText("");
        navigation.dispatch(action)
      },
    },
  ]
);
```

Comment: Thanks @gwl002 but it doesn't work for my problem. I added more code to better represent what I want

Comment: Have you checked the hasUnsavedChanges value when going back? I think even though you have  saved  it's  still true.

Comment: Yes, the value is true but I don't know how to change it. I have tried hasUnsavedChanges = false and setFlagModify (false) but with no success. I'm not really finding mode